# Indian eVisa Process

Tags: visas, india, uk-citizens

I am a British passport holder planning a trip to India in March next year. 
I am trying to find out if I am eligible to apply for an Indian **Tourist** visa via the eVisa process. I have held a multiple entry business visa in the past, but that has now expired.

Does the fact I held a business visa mean I cannot go via the eVisa route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Government of India](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/tvoa.html) for an eTV:

> Eligibility
>
> International Travellers whose sole objective of visiting India is recreation  sight seeing, casual visit to meet friends or relatives, short duration medical treatment or casual business visit.
>
> Passport should have at least six months validity from the date of arrival in India. The passport should have at least two blank pages for stamping by the Immigration Officer.
>
> International Travellers should have return ticket or onward journey ticket, with sufficient money to spend during his/her stay in India.
>
> International Travellers having Pakistani Passport or Pakistani origin may please apply for regular Visa at Indian Mission.
>
> Not available to Diplomatic/Official Passport Holders.
>
> Not available to individuals endorsed on Parent's/Spouse's Passport i.e. each individual should have a separate passport.
>
> Not available to International Travel Document Holders.

So, it seems you qualify.